# React ag-grid group by row

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I was reading ag-grid documentation and I was wondering is it possible to group by row instead of column?

I know you simply need to put `rowGroup: true` on the column but what if I want to do a custom row group.

```
this.state = {
  columnDefs: [{
    headerName: "Make", field: "make"
  }, {
    headerName: "Model", field: "model"
  },{
    headerName: "Price", field: "price"
  }],
  rowData: [{
    make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000
  },{
    make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000
  }]
}
```

From the **example** if my data brings back two row category "Toyota" and "Ford" and I want to only group "Ford" row. How can I achieve this?

```
Make |Model
_______
Toyota
_______
v Ford

      Mondeo....
```

Visual representation of the table I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are for master detail rows:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#example-simple-master-detail

Comment: Close however I would like it to follow the Group row behaviour https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/ as this one actually creates a separate table under "Ford" row

Comment: Not sure that is possible. As a last possibility you could have a look at fullt width rows: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/ This will allow you to display anything you want in a row.